# Restricting droppable elements on div

Tags: jquery

I'm creating and appending a droppable div element like this :

```
    var drop = {
                  drop: function(event, ui) {
                      var add = $("#"+this.id);
                      $('<div id='+counter+' "><div class="myCss">here</div></div>').droppable( drop ).appendTo( "#myDivs");
                      //debugger;
                      counter++;
                  }
                };
```

Can I update this div to just allow divs of a certain id or css to be allowed to be dropped ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```
.droppable( 
    drop: function(event, ui) {
         var targetId = $(this).attr("id");
         //your conditions to check id/class of div . 
         if (targetId == '<your div id to restrict>'){
            return;
         }
    }
)
```

Comment: can this be used also to restrict based on css value ?

Comment: you have element `$(this)` . so use `.css()` to get style and based on value you can do anything.